# Slowly Changing Dimension: Update "row is current" value

Tags: sql-server, ssis, scd

I have a customer SSIS package that is configured to be a slowly changing dimension.

During the wizard, when choosing either the is current or the start-end date option, I have chosen the start and end date options. I also have a column called `RowIsCurrent` It has a `bit (boolean)` data type with a default value of `1`.

I am trying to configure the `SCD` to change the value from `1` to `0` when the SCD ends a historical row. I thought I could just add a line to the `derived column task` that sets the end date.

I am most likely missing something rather elementary, but alas I don't know where I've gone wrong.